# jQuery can't make 2 changes in one action?

Tags: jquery, events, checkbox, attributes

[Here is the link on simple example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8xMU/8/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=checkbox]').live("click", function() {
    if($(this).attr('class') == 'color_checkboxes') {
      if($(this).attr('id') == 'is_checked') {
        $(this).removeAttr('id');
        $(this).attr('checked', false);
      } else {
        $('input[type=checkbox][class=color_checkboxes]').attr('checked', false);
        $(this).attr('checked', true).attr('id', 'is_checked');                
      }
    }
  })
});
```

​

The goal is to check one checkbox - add it the ID value `is_checked`, click on an other one and to this checkbox add the ID `is_checked` and remove the ID `is_checked` to the previous one.

Example - check the checkbox **green**, then **blue** and then again **green** - the green button will be not checked - I mean, that the reason is`is_checked`. When you try to check second time the **green** button, then it works already.

That's not much user-friendly behavior, so I would like to ask you, if there is some way/suggestion, how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use radio buttons?

Comment: As @Jason says, if you always want only one checkbox checked, use radio buttons. That's what they are there for.

Comment: sure it will be, but I just played with and found this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var checkboxes = $('.color_checkboxes:checkbox');

    checkboxes.click(function(e) {
        var clicked = $(this);

        checkboxes.not(clicked).removeAttr('id').attr('checked', false);

        if(clicked.attr('checked')) {
            clicked.attr('id', 'is_clicked');
        } else {
            clicked.removeAttr('id');
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xkMKk/1/

Comment: should be using `.prop("checked", true/false)` instead of `.attr()`.

Comment: should also be using `.on("click", ...)` instead of `.click()`

Comment: @Scott, "should"? Why? `attr` was changed but restored, and `click()` still works. I could understand "could".

Comment: @Scott: `on` substitutes `bind`, `delegate` and `live`, but not the shorthand methods. There is nothing wrong with `click()`.

Comment: @eyelidlessness - `.attr()` is not the recommended way to handle properties. Yes it still works, but that's really for backward compatibility due to people griping about it. `.prop()` was made to handle get/set for properties. And `.click()` obviously still works, as it is shorthand, but again, it's just recommended to bind everything through `.on()` for a consistent look throughout code.

Comment: @scott, unfortunately your arguments are based on style and preference rather than some programming need. It's just as valid to say that you "should" use `attr` for properties which have attribute equivalents, in order to distinguish attributes from properties. The use of `click()` etc for core events likewise allows distinction between core events and non-core events. I think it's problematic in general to promote preferred programming *style* as "shoulds".

Comment: @eyelidlessness - Point taken. Should is the wrong word, as it's not programmatically required. I would still hold that if we are operating on the "could" level, it's still "best" to do what jQuery itself recommends with respect to prop vs attr. I'll concede my point on the core events, as you make a good point there.

Comment: @Scott, jQuery recommends: "To retrieve and change DOM properties, use the .prop() method." It does not say "to retrieve and change node attributes". To me, that means it recommends that you use `attr()` for something like `checked` (an attribute) and use `prop()` for something like `offsetHeight` (a property). Yes, the DOM allows attributes to be **overridden** by properties of the same (camelCased) name, but I don't think that falls under the jQuery recommendation, and I certainly wouldn't say it's preferable. `setAttribute()` was added to DOM for a reason.

Comment: @eyelidlessness - http://api.jquery.com/prop/ states: `According to the W3C forms specification, the checked attribute is a boolean attribute, which means the corresponding property is true if the attribute is present at all—even if, for example, the attribute has no value or an empty string value. The preferred cross-browser-compatible way to determine if a checkbox is checked is to check for a "truthy" value on the element's property using one of the following:`

Comment: `if ( elem.checked )
if ( $(elem).prop("checked") )
if ( $(elem).is(":checked") )`

Comment: `If using jQuery 1.6, the code if ( $(elem).attr("checked") ) will retrieve the actual content attribute, which does not change as the checkbox is checked and unchecked. It is meant only to store the default or initial value of the checked property. To maintain backwards compatability, the .attr() method in jQuery 1.6.1+ will retrieve and update the property for you so no code for boolean attributes is required to be changed to .prop().`

Comment: **`Nevertheless, the preferred way to retrieve a checked value is with one of the options listed above.`**

Comment: @Scott, then the spec is inconsistent in its recommendations. Apart from 1.6 (before 1.6.1), there's no chance that using `attr()` will render incorrect results, and since "checked" refers to an attribute, I see no meaningful reason not to use `attr()`. Your preference (and that of one of the two jQuery recommendations) is still a style preference, not a matter of correctness.

Comment: @eyelidlessness - Again, jQuery is not inconsistent. http://api.jquery.com/attr/ states: `As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. In addition, .attr() should not be used on plain objects, arrays, the window, or the document. To retrieve and change DOM properties, use the .prop() method.` I really don't understand what's so hard to understand. My point has never been about "will it work".  My point is about following jQuery's recommendation to use their methods how they intend for them to be used.

Comment: @Scott, "In addition, .attr() should not be used on plain objects, arrays, the window, or the document. To retrieve and change DOM properties, use the .prop() method." `checked` is none of those cases and that's where the inconsistency in recommendation arises. It is an **attribute**. That is **what `attr()` is for**. The explanation you've provided for use of `prop()` to access an **attribute** would essentially invalidate any use of `attr()` for any purpose. Is that your position? Or can you clarify when you would use `attr()`?

Comment: @eyelidlessness - Based on what the documentation states, what I take away is that `.prop() ` should primarily be used for cases that result in boolean evaluations: readonly, disabled, checked, etc. Those properties are only on the element based on whether the value is true, or `checked="checked"` for example. That would say that `.attr()` should then be used for everything else.  Cases where you want to update, add, or remove a "permanent" if you will attribute to the element. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Though you should use `radio buttons` here is the checkboxed version:

```
$('input[type=checkbox].color_checkboxes').click(function() {
    if (this.checked)
        $(this).siblings().prop('checked', false);
});​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dRD6y/1)

Comment: Doesn't function like a radio button.  Because you can uncheck the selected checkbox. However, I don't think the behavior was noted.

Answer (score 0):

something like this.

```
<script>
  $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
    $("#is_checked").removeAttr("id");
    $(this).attr("id","is_checked");
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can re-factor that a lot. First, you should be binding to [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) through [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), as [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated. Secondly, you should cache all of the checkboxes into a variable.  Thirdly, you should use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) as of version 1.6 for handling properties instead of [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).  Then, you simply check all checkboxes' checked property to false while selecting the current checkbox's check property to true.

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $checkboxes = $("input[type=checkbox]");

    $checkboxes.on("change", function() {

        $checkboxes.prop("checked", false);
        $(this).prop("checked", true);

    });

});
​
```

***[Click here to view jsFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8xMU/11/)***

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){      

    $(document).on("click", ".color_checkboxes:checkbox", function() {
        $(".is_checked").prop("checked", false).removeClass("is_checked");
        $(this).addClass("is_checked");
    });      

});
```

​

First, I would use .on() instead of .live(), because live is deprecated.

Then, instead of using removing and adding IDs, I think it would be wiser to use Classes because there's functions made especially for that. Don't forget that it is possible to have multiple classes!

By using .on(), we can use it to bind it classes ".color_checkboxes" (that are also :checkbox).

When it's clicked, crawl for everything that has class "is_checked", uncheck them, then remove the class.

Then, add the class "is_checked" to the clicked checkbox.

Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Q8xMU/15/

Cheers.